# Is this sanitizer vulnerable to XSS?

Tags: javascript, django, security, beautifulsoup, xss

To have a simple and secure editor for text fields of a django app, I have this snippet to sanitize input html into django code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def sanitize_html(value):
  tag_whitelist = ['img','b','strong','blockquote', 'a']
  attr_whitelist = ['src', 'alt', 'width', 'height', 'href','class']
  soup = BeautifulSoup(value)
  for tag in soup.find_all():
      if tag.name.lower() in tag_whitelist:
          tag.attrs = { name: value for name, value in tag.attrs.items() 
              if name.lower() in attr_whitelist }
      else:
          tag.unwrap()   

  # scripts can be executed from comments in some cases
  try:
    comments = soup.find_all(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment))
    for comment in comments:
      comment.extract()
  except:
    pass
  return unicode(soup)
```

I have also blacklisted entering `javascript` in model fields using this method:

```
BADLIST = ['javascript']

def no_js (text):
    if any(e in text for e in BADLIST):
        raise ValidationError("Your text contains bad words!")
    else:
        return True
```

On the other hand, in template I need to use `{{text| safe}}` to allow healthy html tags to be displayed.

So I'm wondering with these constraint, wether the input is still vulnarable to XSS? And if so, how to fix it?

Comment: Why wouldn't you use something like *bleach* which is an established library for this matter?

Comment: @Wtower I have not heard of that! thanks for introduction.

Comment: Is this going to filter out things like `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript` since it contains "javascript"? Is it going to filter out `href="JAVASCRIPT:alert(1);"` (case-sensitive)? What about data urls like `data:text/html;base64,PHNjcmlwdD5hbGVydCgxKTwvc2NyaXB0Pg==`?

Answer (score 1):

On a first glance the code looks ok, but checking for security vulnerabilities is something not to be taken lightly and needs a bit of time investment to check on your own.

For instance, test if providing a string such as `<script>alert('hello')</script>` is executed. Apart from this simplistic test, there are many things to check. There is much documentation on the matter.

Furthermore, as mentioned in my comment, I would strongly recommend you to use an established library for sanitizing input. Such a library is [bleach](https://bleach.readthedocs.org/en/latest/):

> Bleach is a whitelist-based HTML sanitization and text linkification library. It is designed to take untrusted user input with some HTML.
>
> Because Bleach uses html5lib to parse document fragments the same way browsers do, it is extremely resilient to unknown attacks, much more so than regular-expression-based sanitizers.

This way you are sure at least that your attack surface is smaller, since this software is much more tested and you owuld only have to worry about your allowed HTML tags rather than if your code works.

Usage example:

```
import bleach
mystring = bleach.clean(form.cleaned_data['mystring'], 
                        tags=ALLOWED_TAGS,
                        attributes=ALLOWED_ATTRIBUTES, 
                        styles=ALLOWED_STYLES, 
                        strip=False, strip_comments=True)
```

Comment: So while whitelisting the tags and attrs above, does applying bleach before saving text make `{{text| safe}}` completely safe against XSS?

Comment: Not necessarily, depends on what you allow in. The default `ALLOWED_TAGS`, `ALLOWED_ATTRIBUTES` and `ALLOWED_STYLES` are pretty strict and safe.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely unsafe. BeautifulSoup defaults to using the lxml.html parser, and one can likely exploit differences between this and the browsers' parsers (all following the HTML spec) to smuggle through strings that the browser will see as an element but your code will not. Using BeautifulSoup with html5lib would alleviate that possible attack surface, as then you have a parser identical to browsers.

You probably don't want to allow width, height, and class as it would allow the attacker to make their image the entire size of the page.

Still, in general, I would agree with Wtower's answer that using an established third-party library is likely safer.